# Plumbing not draining after reassembly

Tags: plumbing

My sink seal came loose and so I replaced it last night. Before taking it apart to replace, it was draining fine. After putting it back together, it doesn't drain at all, one side of the sink slightly does. With some heavy plunging, some of the water will go down.

What could I have done wrong in assembling it that would make it not drain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if drain plumbing is not done right, it will drain perfectly fine...  onto your floor.  For it not to drain, means you have a blockage.  Take the parts you fixed apart and do an inspection for any clogs.  If they are free, assume the blockage is farther down the line.  If that is the case, use a hand snake and snake out the drain before you put it back together again (make it easier).  Reassemble and see if it drains.  If it doesn't drain, try snaking again.  Typically the cost of a hand snake is cheaper than calling out a plumber.

Comment: It looks like the air valve is not working correctly. There may be a clog just past that.

Comment: According to my mother w=who I live with (and threw it back together whatever way she wanted) it really does look like the air valve. If it is manually opened and held open, it'll work fine.

Comment: Looks like you will need to replace the air valve.  Having a blocked vent/air valve will cause the sink to drain slowly.  The air valves are designed to open on their own, looks like yours has last that in the work done.

Comment: Also make sure the plumbing y for the air valve is installed correctly.  The y should be setup so as the waste water flows it will suck air into the link.